# Create Master and detail records in single insert without external ID

Tags: api, master-detail, externalid

I can't seem to find a direct answer for this... I am hoping to create a master record and one or more detail records in a single API call. Most resources have suggested the use of an external ID, but I'd rather not go that route. Ideally, I'd like to be able to do the following in a single API call:

1) Create a master record
2) Create a detail record with the record ID of the master record

This is pretty straightforward to do with two separate API calls as I can get the master record ID from the first call, but I was hoping this could be done in a single call.

Comment: Without an external ID from the master record to reference from the detail records, how are you going to indicate which master record belongs to which detail record?

Comment: I was hoping the API would provide some type of mechanism wherein the result of one insert could populate a field in a subsequent insert, but it doesn't sound like that is the case.

Comment: Are you willing to create (and call) your own @RestResource or WebService class? That could accept the master and detail objects, insert the master, set the master ID on the detail and then insert the detail.

Comment: I've never really explored RestResource, sounds promising. The functionality I am creating here is slated to be part of a managed package, are there any limitations from that perspective that might prevent me from using it?

Comment: Shouldn't be; I have @RestResource classes in managed packages. What you can change once you've released is limited as they are global and the URL pattern gets locked down too. They do have to be exposed through profiles or permission sets to be callable too (which if you have many classes can be inconvenient).

Comment: Why don't you want to use an externalId for this?